# How to calculate a sum of sequence of numbers in Prolog

Tags: loops, prolog

The task is to calculate a sum of natural numbers from 0 to M. I wrote the following code using SWI-Prolog:

```
my_sum(From, To, _) :- From > To, !.
my_sum(From, To, S) :-
  From = 0,
  Next is 1,
  S is 1,
  my_sum(Next, To, S).
my_sum(From, To, S) :-
  From > 0,
  Next is From + 1,
  S is S + Next,
  my_sum(Next, To, S).
```

But when I try to calculate:

```
my_sum(0,10,S), writeln(S).
```

I got False instead of correct number. What is going wrong with this example?

Comment: `my_sum(From, To, _) :- From > To, !.` means it succeeds if `From` is greater than `To` and provide an undefined result. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is surely false for Next \= 0: `S is S + Next`. Another more fundamental problem is that you're doing the computation in 'reverse' order. That is, when `From > To` and the program stop, you don't 'get back' the result. Then you should add an accumulator (another parameter, to be propagated to all recursive calls) and unify it with the partial sum at that last step...

Anyway, should be simpler:

```
my_sum(From, To, S) :-
  From < To,
  Next is From + 1,
  my_sum(Next, To, T),
  S is T + From.
my_sum(N, N, N).

| ?- my_sum(2, 4, N).
N = 9
```

Comment: Please, can you explain why S is S + Next results in False?

Comment: Variables in Prolog are not modifiable: can only be free or bound to a value. Then the evaluation of S is S + N will surely fail for N \= 0

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm starting see the light ))

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ - to elaborate on CapelliC's comment, "variables" in Prolog don't work like variables in most other languages. They aren't freely assignable. In Prolog, a variable is "instantiated" by the language in an attempt to make something succeed and, once instantiated, it can't be re-instantiated except through backtracking.

Comment: why oh why do you suggest the non-TR solution? (I just can't upvote non-TR code).

Comment: @WillNess: just helping the OP. TR will come later, I hope :)

Comment: I mean, while you're there already, and you've mentioned the accumulator, you could just add the 4th argument for the same price. I also think that TR solutions are much easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write the predicate along these lines, using a worker predicate with an additional accumulator:

```
sum(X,Y,Z) :-
  integer(X)   ,
  integer(Y)   ,
  sum(X,Y,0,Z)
  .

sum(X,X,T,Z) :- Z is T+X .
sum(X,Y,T,Z) :- X < Y , X1 is X+1 , T1 is T+X , sum(X1,Y,T1,Z) .
sum(X,Y,T,Z) :- X > Y , X1 is X-1 , T1 is T+X , sum(X1,Y,T1,Z) .
```

This implementation is simple, bi-directional, meaning that `sum(1,3,X)` and `sum(3,1,X)` both yield 6 as a result (1+2+3), and tail recursive, meaning that it should be able to  handle a range of any size without a stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

As it happens, there's a purely analytic solution as well:

```
sum(N, Sum) :- Sum is N * (N+1) / 2.
```

In use:

```
?- sum(100, N).
N = 5050.
```

You used the loop tag so this probably isn't an answer you desire, but it's good to prefer this kind of solution when one exists.

Comment: how about calculating `sum $ take 200 $ drop 176 $ cycle [1,7..242]`, can we easily come up with a closed solution there too? (pardon the Haskell syntax). :) that's not a critique or anything, just a commentary, :) perhaps a pointless one.

Answer (score 0):

```
predicates
 sum(integer,integer)

clauses
 sum(0,0).
 sum(N,R):-
     N1=N-1,
     sum(N1,R1),
     R=R1+N.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But please take a few minutes to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get some useful tips on answering questions. Esp. the part "fuller explanations are better". Meaning: please explain why this answers the question (better than existing answers).